# Changing jframe attributes without actionperformed?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a hotkey program using jnativehook however I'm unable to change the color of say a button when I press a key (outside focus). The key press and everything works fine but I'm guessing it needs some kind of actionperformed to "refresh" the gui?

At the moment I just have a simple listener that goes to setstartbtn function whenever f12 is pressed:

```
 boolean s = false;
 public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent nke) {       
    if (nke.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_F12){
       setstartbtn();

    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


  public void setstartbtn(){

             jButton1.setBackground(Color.red);
             jstartlabel.setForeground(Color.red);
             mainrot = false;

}
```

If I assign the 2nd function to the button itself then it works fine.

It's the same issue for example if I have a countdown timer, when the timer reaches 0 from 10, the button should turn green but it doesn't so I'm guessing it needs action performed?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: here is the full project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lfqziqbvszfr2hs/AABlyJGlb_UvIljEBUwMrpRza?dl=0

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd start with some debug statements and make sure your methods are actually getting called the way you expect them to

Comment: Yeah it gets called fine, even steps into setbackground, but doesn't update the gui. revalidate or repaint didn't seem to do anything either (tried it in the alone, and on the button itself).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void setstartbtn(){

         jButton1.setBackground(Color.red);
         jstartlabel.setForeground(Color.red);
         mainrot = false;
         revalidate();
         repaint();
}
```

Try repaint() if revalidate doesn't work.

Comment: `setBackground` is a bound property, meaning it should be setting up a `repaint` of itself, `revalidate` has more to do with the updating the layout then anything else. I'd recommend starting with a `System.out.println` to make sure the method is been called and verifying the instances of the objects are the same as those on the screen before attacking `repaint` or `revalidate` - IMHO

Comment: It's going through that method fine, even debugged and it called everything. I added the full project in the main topic.

Comment: I downloaded your project, it seems like you need jButton1.setOpaque(true); for red background to be visible. (Note I tested with only the swing components)